# Javascript not working neither locally nor github pages

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I had forked [autoComplete.js/demo](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/demo/) and deployed my fork on github pages at [My Github repo](https://github.com/caycaycarly/caycaycarly.github.io) - > https://caycaycarly.github.io/. All the source locations are correct, css works, but not javascript. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a quick look, I see that there are some errors in your code, you are trying to access DOM elements without them getting mounted/loaded. Please check them out.

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you forgot to put the json data folder in your forked pages, check using console (f12)